# Not sure why Facebook is cropping image posted by iPhone differently in mobile version and desktop version.

Tags: ios, facebook, image

Not sure why Facebook is cropping image posted by iPhone differently in mobile version and desktop version.

The scenario is: I have captured the image using iPhone6 plus. My app posts url links of the image though the graph api . In FB mobile version , the image is shown completely with center cropped, and the behavior is consistent for all the images. But when the same posts is open in desktop-browser , some image is not centered cropped and is cropped from bottom and only upper half of image is visible . 
Can someone explain why facebook is behaving wired  for some images.

Comment: Maybe this will help answer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images